# Singularities in an Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, singularity

these might sound like extremely trivial questions but since my background is more in probability and statistics I'm not too sure what to do, or even what to read up on to understand what to do. I believe that my equation might be behaving irregularly due to singularity point(s), however, I don't know how to test the equation to discover whether there are singularity points in it.

By singularity I mean as defined in the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)

Say for instance I have an equation of the form:

$$f(x,0) = a( b(x) - c(x))$$

where $a$ is a constant, and $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are functions (to be precise, $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are both very simple first order PDEs). Now, for this equation, whenever I put particular values into $b(x)$ and $c(x)$, then the equation $f(x,0)$ will not have any singularities, but for certain other values which are put into $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ then there are singularities. For example, say for instance I put $x^{2}$ into the functions $b(x)$ and $c(x)$, then the function $f(x,0)$ will not have any singularities. However, if I instead put $\log(x)$ into $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ then the function $f(x,0)$ will now have a singularity.

**Now, my questions are:**

> *Firstly,* is there any way for me to test the equation to determine whether there are any singularities in it? Is there a theorem or a method or something which I can apply to the equation which will allow me to check whether there are any singularities in it? In particular, since $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are a type of PDE, is there a theorem which says something like "For a PDE to have a singularity it must satisfy the following properties:... " or something like that? (I know that's not realistic but I just meant that as an example).
>
> *Secondly,* if I do find singularities in the equation is there any way for me to remove them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific?  I feel like your question is too vague to provide a meaningful answer.  It also depends on what you mean by singularity.  A trivial answer to your question would be: a function is not singular if it is bounded, in other words, a function is not unbounded if it is bounded.  Are the differential equations tags appropriate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I initially included the differential equation tags due to the fact that the equations for $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are differential equations (they are both a simple first order PDE to be precise). However, I decided to omit this information to try and keep things as general as possible considering how little I know about singularities. (I've edited this information in now). Is there any further information I should include to improve these questions?